# A simple variable count inside array

Tags: perl, hash, count

After working with this code, I am stuck at what I think is a simple error, yet I need outside eyes to see what is wrong.

I used unpack function to divide an array into the following.

```
@extract = 

------MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM-M-MMMMMMMM  
------SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS-S-SSSSSDTA
------TIIIIIIIIIIIIITIIIVVIIIIII-I-IIIIITTT
```

Apparently, after unpacking into the array, when I try to go into the while loop, @extract shows up completely empty. Any idea as to why this is happening?
    print @extract; #<-----------Prints input

```
my $sum = 0;
my %counter = ();
while (my $column = @extract) {
print @extract; #<------- This extract is completely empty. Should be input

for (my $aa = (split ('', $column))){
    $counter{$aa}++;
    delete $counter{'-'}; # Don't count -
    }

    # Sort keys by count descending  

    my @keys = (sort {$counter{$b} <=> $counter{$a}} keys %counter) [0]; #gives highest letter
    for my $key (@keys) {
        $sum += $counter{$key};
        print OUTPUT "$key   $counter{$key}   ";
```

Comment: start by writing code that gets the highest count for a single line; then wrap a loop over your lines around that; you seem to be confusing the two tasks here.

Comment: You are right ysth, got to add another loop element so as to count the individuals. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line is an array element correct? I don't see in your code where you are checking the individual characters.

Assuming the input that you have shown is a 3 element array containing the line as a string:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @entries;

while(my $line = shift(@extract)){
    my %hash;
    for my $char(split('', $line)){
        if($char =~ /[a-zA-Z]/) { $hash{$char}++ }
    }

    my $high;
    for my $key (keys %hash) { 
        if(!defined($high)){ $high = $key }
        elsif($hash{$high} < $hash{$key}){ 
            $high = $key
        }
    }

    push @entries, {$high => $hash{$high}};
}
```

Note this empties @extract, if you don't want to do that you'd have to use a for loop like below

```
for my $i (0 .. $#extract){
    #my %hash etc...
}
```

EDIT:
Changed it so that only the highest number is actually kept

Comment: Thanks Gabs00, will give this a try ASAP. Appreciate the time and effort.

Comment: You don't have to use array indexes with `for`, you can just use `for my $line (@extract)`.

Comment: @TLP, that is correct, for me its a form of habit since I usually need to know the index.

Comment: @Gabs00 Your post is logical, I tried to run it with my given input but it is not getting any results. Will keep you updated.

Comment: @Gyler does it give any results?

Comment: @Gabs00 Finally got it to work, after lots of hard work! Thanks again for your help, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

An approach using reduce from List::Util.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 'reduce';

my @extract = qw/
------MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM-M-MMMMMMMM
------SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS-S-SSSSSDTA
------TIIIIIIIIIIIIITIIIVVIIIIII-I-IIIIITTT
/;


for (@extract) {
    my %count;
    tr/a-zA-Z//cd;
    for (split //) {
        $count{$_}++;   
    }
    my $max = reduce { $count{$a} > $count{$b} ? $a : $b } keys %count;
    print "$max $count{$max}\n";
}
```